# Call C function from specific memory address? (TI code composer studio 3.3)

Tags: c, memory-management, signal-processing

i`m trying to call a C function which resides in a specific memory address (0x100h) but every time i look at the function call with JTAG debugger, it just jumps over it (no function call) and proceeds with the next line of code. I put the called function in #pragma code_section(called_func, "FUNC_SEC")  to link it to the memory address. Actual function resides in funcs.c file.

My project.cmd linker file has the following memory and sections lines..

```
MEMORY
{
FUNC_SEC         : origin = 0x000100, length = 0x0000ff
}

SECTIONS {
CALLED_FUNC     : LOAD = FUNC_SEC,   PAGE = 0 {
  ..\release\Tests.obj(.text)
 } 
}
```

When looking at the 0x100h address, it is empty, which would explain the function not working properly. What i`m trying to accomplish is to call a function which resides in a DSPs (TMS320c28x) RAM area and execute it. After it has done its thing, the program resumes in the DSPs flash memory area.

Note, function names etc have been changed..

Can someone can help me with this problem? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you want to review your start up routines. Is your function is getting copied correctly from load address to execute address.

Comment: The problem was solved by transferring the function to internal flash. So you`re probably right about the start up routines.